# Programmatically deselecting a radio button by clicking its label

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label, fieldset

I was looking for a script that allows me to deselect a radio button.  I found one on SO and implemented it here...

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/YFsVK/1/

As you can see it's working great but only when you click on the radio button itself.  (You can also "select" a button by clicking on its corresponding `<label>` text.  This is how the `<label>` operates by default.)

However, I also need to be able to "deselect" a radio button by only clicking on its corresponding `<label>`, and this is where I need some help.

(Why?  Because I'm using a plugin that graphically alters the look of the radio button using an image sprite contained within the `<label>` that covers over the default radio buttons.  There is a line within my jsFiddle you can activate to see the plugin in action.)

I'm sure I just need to tweak this script a bit but I cannot seem to get it correct.  I believe I just need to "select" the `<label>` while manipulating the corresponding radio button.  A `<label>` is "attached" to a button by placing the `id` of the button in the `for` attribute of the corresponding `<label>`.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name="amount"]').mousedown(function(e) { // allows radio button deselection
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($self.is(':checked')) {
            var uncheck = function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $self.removeAttr('checked');
                }, 0);
            };
            var unbind = function() {
                $self.unbind('mouseup', up);
            };
            var up = function() {
                uncheck();
                unbind();
            };
            $self.bind('mouseup', up);
            $self.one('mouseout', unbind);
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset id="radioset">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="amount" value="Option 1" /><label for="radio-1" title="">Option 1</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="amount" value="Option 2" /><label for="radio-2" title="">Option 2</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="amount" value="Option 3" /><label for="radio-3" title="">Option 3</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="amount" value="Option 4" /><label for="radio-4" title="">Option 4</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="amount" value="Option 5" /><label for="radio-5" title="">Option 5</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Strangely, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YFsVK/2/) doesn't work...

Comment: @alex, but it looks like that _should_ work.

Comment: It is calling the same function with the same `this` reference, so I dunno. Weird.

Comment: I think it's because the radio button is updated just after the `mouseup` event, whereas the above function is called on `mousedown` so basically it cancels out the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried what @Jrod did and noticed the plugin didn't work. So I modified the plugin. Basically adding this to the label:

```
.bind('mouseup', function(){
    if ($(this).is('.checked') && input.is(':radio')) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            label.removeClass('checked focus');
            input.removeAttr('checked').blur();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/YFsVK/4/).

Comment: This is awesome work!  Is there a way to pass a parameter to the plugin to switch this on/off?  Because, I also use this same plugin for radio buttons where I don't want to allow a deselect.

Comment: Here is an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/YFsVK/5/) with the parameter `radioToggle`, set it to anything other than `true` to disable the toggle.

Comment: Sorry to inform but a new problem is caused by the modified plugin.  `TypeError: Result of expression 'option' [undefined] is not an object.`.  `.customInput();` is causing the error but `.customInput({ radioToggle: true });` and `.customInput({ radioToggle: false });` are not.  It pops up in the console when I click on the radio buttons... they seem to operate despite the error but I'd like to clean it up, if possible (don't want to require the parameter).  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, try this [version](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/YFsVK/6/)... basically I changed this line: `if (option && option.radioToggle === true) {`

Comment: I was using this code snippet in a project and recently updated to jQuery 3.1.1 which necessitated some changes - bind() is now deprecated so I switched to using on(). As well, removeAttr(), while it continues to remove the checked attribute on the input no longer seemed to affect the underlying checked value, so I had to switch that line to use input.prop('checked', false) instead of  input.removeAttr('checked'). I hope this helps anyone looking to implement this with a later version of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".radio-label").click(function(e) {

            var radio = $(this).attr("for");
            radio = $("#" +radio );
            if(radio.is(":checked")) {
                e.preventDefault();
                radio.removeAttr("checked");
            }

        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset id="radioset">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="amount" value="Option 1" /><label class="radio-label" for="radio-1" title="">Option 1</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="amount" value="Option 2" /><label class="radio-label" for="radio-2" title="">Option 2</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="amount" value="Option 3" /><label class="radio-label" for="radio-3" title="">Option 3</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="amount" value="Option 4" /><label class="radio-label" for="radio-4" title="">Option 4</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="amount" value="Option 5" /><label class="radio-label" for="radio-5" title="">Option 5</label>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solution works, but for some reason it fails when the plugin is activated.  http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/YFsVK/3/